# How to export the SSRS report in excel

Tags: ssrs, ssrs-2016, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008

I have 7 pages in my SSRS report and also I'm used page break option. Is there any way available to export all the pages in single excel sheet. Please provide me solutions

Comment: See this question where this was already asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/965013/reporting-services-export-data-to-excel-in-only-one-sheet

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried this way while export all pages i'm getting result in single page but the column heading won't repeated in excel. E.g If the 1st pages contains 10 rows same vice versa for all other pages and all the pages have the column headers, while export into excel I'm getting only one column headers for all the pages. I want to repeat the column name for each ten rows. Please provide me solutions